# ClientRect is suddenly not defined

Tags: javascript, dom, getboundingclientrect

In the past week or so my UI prototype project that used `if (foo instanceof ClientRect)` to catch a specific user interaction stopped working and began to throw `Uncaught ReferenceError: ClientRect is not defined`. My local version stopped working, but also online versions that haven't been updated since April and worked just fine.

Somehow the project only still works on Opera version 45.0. After updating it to 48.0 it stopped working on Opera as well.

Has some update happened that could cause this behaviour?

Comment: The correct prototype name is `DOMRect`, not sure where ClientRect came from. Ah [from IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826029(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: I changed it to `foo instanceof DOMRect` and it works again. Somehow it worked just fine for months, accessed mainly from Chrome.

Comment: Yes was changed recently in chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=719246

Comment: add an interface ClientRect extends DOMRect or simply replace the former with the latter and update your code.

Answer (score 3):

`DOMRect` is the standard you are looking for. `ClientRect` is legacy:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=719246

See more about `DOMRect`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMRect